# what are the files to include for pnotify

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pnotify

this is the result of pnotify after I included the following files:
 `prettify.js` && `prettify.css` && `jquery.pnotify.default.css` && `jquery.pnotify.default.icons.css` && of course `jquery.pnotify.js`

[image]

am I missing something ?

Comment: plz help us, I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include these files `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js`

Comment: well this solved the problem, but it missed up the style, so i have to clear the general style, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included jQuery UI Icons in your page? I tried to get the issue replicated, but I got pnotify working correctly on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hunkyhari/LFXmn/12/).

```
$.pnotify.defaults.styling = "jqueryui";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.pnotify({
        title: 'Regular Notice',
        text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 try to change `jquery.pnotify.js` like this:

```
bootstrap: {
            container: "alert",
            notice: "alert-warning",
            notice_icon: "icon-exclamation-sign",
            info: "alert-info",
            info_icon: "icon-info-sign",
            success: "alert-success",
            success_icon: "icon-ok-sign",
            error: "alert-danger",
            error_icon: "icon-warning-sign",
            closer: "icon-remove",
            pin_up: "icon-pause",
            pin_down: "icon-play",
            hi_menu: "well",
            hi_btn: "btn",
            hi_btnhov: "",
            hi_hnd: "icon-chevron-down"
```